# Is there any way to find who created light weight tag in GIT repository?

Tags: git

Is there any way to find who created a light weight tag in git repository.

I have tried "git show tagname" but its only displaying the details of commit it is pointing to.

Any other possible way?

Answer (score 0):

Via Git it isn't possible. You need to use annotated tags if you want that functionality. Though if you know who has access to the repo, you could try asking everyone that has access if it was them.

Comment: But someone created a lightweight tag which is creating mess in our repository. Any way to figureout who created it?

Comment: @Paul: not with Git. Does your OS have NSA Orange Book audit security? That would let you do it.